# Fadeout In Primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am developing a mobile application in primefaces 5.1 and JSF 2.0

While clicking the menu button a side menu bar has to come and fill the 50% if the page and the rest of the page has to fade out.

I tried Using

```
<p:button id="showme" value="Show Me" onclick="return false">
   <p:effect type="fade" event="click" for="myPanel"/>
        <h:panelGroup layout="block" id="myPanel" style="display:none">
            page content
        </h:panelGroup>
</p:button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not a modal dialog where you can define position, height, width, and resize (false) attributes?

http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/mobile/dialog.xhtml

Comment: Then menu has to appear be in side bar. Like facebook. I made that sidepar. All i want is to fadeout the present content when the menu bar appears